# Original manuscripts of 16th century composers

Tags: notation, rhythm, renaissance-music

**TL;DR** - Where can I find manuscripts by Renaissance composers?

I'm studying 16th Century counterpoint and the shift in rhythmic notation from "longer" note values to "shorter" values.

*(In the Renaissance the whole note, half note, and quarter note predominate with the half note functioning as the beat, carrying the harmony, etc.  There are frequent double-whole notes.  By the Baroque period, however, we see much more quarter, eighth, and sixteenth note activity.  Double-whole notes are very rare and the quarter note frequently carries the beat and the harmony.  This is a generalization, but a quick analysis of Palestrina and Bach side to side would illustrate well enough.)*

Before I make any claims about when and how that shift occured, I'd like to view some primary materials.  Where can I find either original manuscripts or published copies from that time period for well-known composers like Palestrina, DesPrez, and Gabrielli.  I suspect that when I find 16th Century music on imslp, for instance, it has largely been heavily edited for modern musicians.

Comment: Willi Apel describes and explains almost everything: https://archive.org/details/notationofpolyph1953apel/page/152/mode/2up

Comment: As Albrecht said, Apel gives a lot of details to answer your question about the shift in note values, and there are plenty of other secondary sources that explain that shift.  As for IMSLP and the CPDL, there's now a surprising number of PDFs of original sources and sometimes links (particularly on CPDL) to library PDFs and facsimiles, including plenty of original published sources from ca. 1600 and before.  Just be aware that in many cases you may be encountering part books or choirbook format, rather than scores, which didn't become common for polyphonic music until after 1600.

Answer (score 2):

I checked several sites but most used modern notation (with a few measure incipit in the original.) There are several university libraries that have some, but I only have access to a few.

"The Morgan Library and Museum" seems to have an extensive collection. There are free things from the Library of Congress (modern and older popular music and Renaissance and Medieval dance) so there might be something useful in there collection.

I'd suggest using Google or Duck-Duck-Go or whatever your favorite search engine happens to be and explore.

Answer (score 2):

When you google  *renaissance music notation* and search for **images** you will find many links and sites:

https://www.google.com/search?q=renaissance+music+notation&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwie9_v7msvxAhWUwLsIHUMzBGQQ2-cCegQIABAC&oq=renaissance+music+notation&gs_lcp=ChJtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1pbWcQAzIECAAQEzoECCMQJzoGCAAQBxAeULjyAVjjiwJgvZECaABwAHgAgAGuAYgBiAWSAQMxLjSYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-img&ei=VpriYJ70EJSB7_UPw-aQoAY&bih=582&biw=320&client=ms-android-samsung-ga-rev1&prmd=ivsn&safe=acti

Also google  for mensural notation and the added links like
https://chmtl.indiana.edu/tml/404.php

For earlier music also search under **codex** and sites of the Roman catholic church.